# Is there a workaround for the issue 6656 in Python 2.6?

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck on Python 2.6 and encountering the [issue 6656](http://bugs.python.org/issue6656) ("locale.format_string fails on escaped percentage"), which seems to be fixed only in 2.7+. Is there any plausible way to work around the problem apart from **not** using `locale.format_string`?

EDIT: I just found out that the issue in question is also supposed to fix [issue 8096](http://bugs.python.org/issue8096) ("locale.format_string fails on mapping keys"). Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make the percent character an interpolated value:

```
locale.format_string('%f%s', (1.0, '%'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.format_string('%f%s', (1.0, '%'))
'1.000000%'
```

Comment: Clever, but won't work in my case. I'm keeping a dict of different formatting string depending on a field I want to format, either with or without percentage depending on a field type. If python could just ignore the additional arguments, I'd be fine, but it doesn't. On second thought, I might catch that "not all arguments converted during string formatting" exception or maybe add `'%'` in case the "not enough arguments for format string" is thrown.

Comment: If you are using a *dictionary* for the formatting parameters and use `'%(n)f%(perc)s', {'n': 1.0, 'perc': '%'}` then it should not complain if there is no placeholder being used for the `perc` key; so  `'%(n)f', {'n': 1.0, 'perc': '%'}` works too. That way you could always add in the `perc` key and not worry about exceptions.

Comment: Clever again, gonna try that. Thanks!

Comment: Would have worked, if not for another python 2.6 bug :( I've edited the question to reflect that, maybe you have a workaround for that too. Otherwise there is no way apart from forking `locale.py` I'm afraid...

Comment: @NikolaiProkoschenko: ah, right, in that case you'd have to parse the `%\(\w+\)[sfdgbx..]` formatting placeholders and convert the whole thing to positional parameters instead. A real pain!